# Appending elements to an array

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

Hi all real newbie question here.

I have an array like this:

```
 var daysInMonth = Array<([MyCustomClass], NSDate)>()
```

How can I append an element to this?

I am having difficulty doing so. Trying something like this:

```
daysInMonth.append([MyCustomClass](), someDate)
```

or

```
daysInMonth.append(  ([MyCustomClass](), someDate)   )
```

will not work (i'd like to add an empty array initial above of type MyCustomClass, as well as some date that I have) but these are failing (error missing parameter #2 in call)

Any thoughts on what I am lacking in my syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're trying to append 2 separate values at once?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but it has a bit of a "code smell" about it.  Rather than using an array of types it is probably better design to define a new struct that has an array of `MyCustomClass` and an NSDate and then declaring an array of those structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a swift bug to me. The swift compiler cannot correctly parse the "( (...) )" as passing in a tuple to a function.

If I break the `append` operation into two statements, it works.

```
var daysInMonth = Array<([MyCustomClass], NSDate)>()

let data = ([MyCustomClass()], NSDate()) // assuming MyCustomClass init() taks no parameter 

daysInMonth.append(data)
```

**note**: It was `[MyCustomClass]()` in your question, which is incorrect.

Comment: Which is better because it is more clear and each statement is doing one thing. But to use the new syntax would be even better.

Comment: @Zaph Yeah, I expect them to be equivalent. So I am bit surprised by the 'bug' (if it is indeed one)

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @Anthony hey I had a question so apparently by doing [MyCustomClass()] it ends up instantiating a new instance of MyCustomClass() and adding it to the array - this produces an array as the first parameter with one object in the array. I actually don't want that, rather an empty array as the first parameter (later i'm going to add my own values). I was going crazy before I realized this because it always had one extra element in the array (and this was why). If I remove the ()'s it doesn't work (same error). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your array using the newer `Array` syntax instead:

```
var daysInMonth = [([MyCustomClass], NSDate)]()
```

Then, this works:

```
daysInMonth.append(([MyCustomClass](), NSDate()))
```